# Pass Parameter to SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

Tags: python, python-2.7, simplehttpserver, basehttpserver, requesthandler

I have to pass a parameter to SimpleHTTPRequestHandler class, so I used class factory to create a custom handler as below.

```
def RequestHandlerClass(application_path):    

  class CustomHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):

    def __init__(self, request, client_address, server):

        SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.__init__(self, request, client_address, server)
        self._file_1_done = False 
        self._file_2_done = False 
        self._application_path = application_path

    def _reset_flags(self):

        self._file_1_done = False 
        self._file_2_done = False 

    def do_GET(self):

        if (self.path == '/file1.qml'):
            self._file_1_done = True  

        if (self.path == '/file2.qml'):
            self._file_2_done = True 

        filepath = self._application_path + '/' + self.path  # Error here

        try:
            f = open(filepath) 
            self.send_response(200)
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(f.read())
            f.close()
        except IOError as e :
            self.send_error(404,'File Not Found: %s' % self.path)    


        if (self._file_1_done and self._file_2_done):
            self._reset_flags()  
            self.server.app_download_complete_event.set()
  return CustomHandler
```

This is my httpserver using the custom handler

```
class PythonHtpServer(BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer, threading.Thread):

  def __init__(self, port, serve_path):
    custom_request_handler_class = RequestHandlerClass(serve_path)
    BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer.__init__(self, ('0.0.0.0', port), custom_request_handler_class)
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.app_download_complete_event = threading.Event()

  def run(self):
    self.serve_forever()

  def stop(self):
    self.shutdown()
```

and I start the server with

```
http_server = PythonHtpServer(port = 8123, serve_path = '/application/main.qml')
```

The server starts, but I get this error

```
AttributeError: CustomHandler instance has no attribute '_application_path'
```

Basically, from the error, the server did start but I don't know why it is not creating the attributes ( or the init is not called ). Please tell me where I am going wrong. Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO the simplest way is to make `_application_path` a static attribute of the class. It is declared only at class declaration time, and can be used transparently by instances of the class:

```
def RequestHandlerClass(application_path):    

  class CustomHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):

    _application_path = application_path   # static attribute

    def __init__(self, request, client_address, server):

        SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.__init__(self, request, client_address, server)
        self._file_1_done = False 
        self._file_2_done = False 

    def _reset_flags(self):
        ...
```

That way every new instance of the custom handler class will have access to the application path as `self._application_path`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here that BaseHttpRequestHandler (and thus its subclass,  SimpleHttpRequestHandler) never makes it out of its `__init__` method:

- HttpServer calls the SimpleHttpRequestHandler's constructor, which percolates up to the parent class' `BaseHttpHandler__init__`...
- [`BaseHttpHandler.__init__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/socketserver.py#L755) calls `handle`, which is overridden in...
- [`BaseHttpRequestHandler.handle`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/http/server.py#L433), which loops forever (given default options).

Thus, if you want to pass info along to your handler, you have to do it before calling the super's `__init__`.  I'm probably several years too late to help you, but for future readers, you can just switch the order of your `__init__`:

```
class CustomHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self._file_1_done = False 
    self._file_2_done = False
    self._application_path = application_path
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

I'd probably also use functools.partial instead of wrapping the whole thing in a function:

```
class CustomHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):

  def __init__(self, application_path, *args, **kwargs):
    self._file_1_done = False 
    self._file_2_done = False
    self._application_path = application_path
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

...

custom_request_handler_class = functools.partial(CustomHandler, serve_path)
BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(('0.0.0.0', port), custom_request_handler_class)
```

It's probably not a great idea to call `super().__init__` at the end of your init *in general* (since it might mess up initialization), but here it seems like Python is kind of forcing your hand.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, you've written something like this (in this e.g., `application_path` ~= `var`):

```
def createClass(var):
    class MyClass:
        def __init__(self):
            self.var = var
        def func(self):
            # use var in some way
            print (self.var)
    # Return class definition
    return MyClass
```

So the class is written to save the variable `var` *when an instance of `MyClass` is created*. However, by the time the function finishes, *the variable is destroyed*, and since the class only returns a class *definition* and not a class *instance*, an instance of `MyClass` does not get created by the time the original variable `var` is destroyed, and thus the variable `var` never actually gets saved by `MyClass`.

INSTEAD, you can add `var` as an argument to the `MyClass.__init__` function, and create a generator class to handle creation of `MyClass` instances, like so:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, var):
        (self.arg1, self.arg2, self.var) = (arg1, arg2, var)
    # Insert other methods as usual

class MyClassGenerator:
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var
    def make(self, arg1, arg2):
        return MyClass(arg1, arg2, var)
```